# Total row visualisation IBM cognos

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi

i have a list where employees are listed and next to it the clients afther that a 1 or 0 if there has been contact with the cliënts for longer than 3 months

now i want to visualise the list but i cant get the total per employee. i have grouped by employee but that doesn't seem te work.

example:

```
**Employee     Cliëntname     longer than 3 months**
    1            1              0
    1            33             1
    1            12             0
             **total          1**
    2            2              1
    2            3              1
             **total          2**
```

can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
total([longer than 3 months] for [Employee])
```

Comment: Hey Johnsonium,

thanks for the answer but unfortunatly this gives me a result of 1 for every employee. the entities i use in de diagram are the employee and longer than 3 months

what else could it be?

Comment: What is the Aggregate Function property for the 'longer than 3 months' column?

Comment: The 'longer than 3 months' column is a calculated field which has the aggregate function propery standaard value. but i've tried all of then while some will give me other numbers none will give me the correct number

Comment: If you set the 'longer than 3 months' column's Aggregate Function to Total and Employee is the only other column on the report, then the 'longer than 3 months' column should roll up with a single row for each employee value and total of all values in 'longer than 3 months'. Make sure 'Auto-group and Summarize' property is set to 'Yes' on the query for this to work. That is the default.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the answer cause it's not working :( i tried everything i can think off

Comment: Can you attach some screen shots? I'd like to see the data items in the queries, and the aggregate function properties of each.

Comment: Sorry for my late reaction (i was on holiday). Unfortunately I do not have permission to provide screenshots of the data items because there is sensitive data in it.

is there another way?

Comment: Can you anonymize it? You can blur out sensitive data, or you can just recreate it using different names/data.

Comment: I will try to do it today. If I have the result I will come back to you, if not I definitely will come back to say I can't do it ;)

Comment: sorry for not replying to you @johnsonium unfortunatly im not able to provide the content for company classification reasons. i did however find a solution to the problem (bit of a work around but it worked in the end) thanks for providing your time anyway!